# How to Split Swift Message?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, split

Guys i am having an issue is i am having an input like this:-

:21:ari
:22:sachin
:23:viru
hazard
:25:sevi

i have to split in such a way that 21 matches to ari,i am splitting the whole input by using line splitter.but i cant match the value hazard with the tag 23 my code is below,any one have a differnt logic please help:-

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String []args){

 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();  
    sb.append(":20:akshay");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":21:ari");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":22:sachin");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":23:viru");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("hazard");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":25:sevi");
    String[] tok = sb.toString().split("\n");
    System.out.println(tok.length);
    for(String string:tok){
        if(string.contains(":")){
            int first=string.indexOf(':');
            int last=string.lastIndexOf(':');
            String tag=string.substring(first+1,last);
            String data=string.substring(last+1);

        }else{

        }

       System.out.println(sb);


    }





     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is expected behaviour for your exapmle? Should 23 correspond to 2 values - "viru" and "hazard"?

I can suggest that each fragment of tag + data is separated from pevious one by combination of characters "\n:"; and there can be multiple data elements separated by "\n" for each tag.

If this is true, then you can modify your splittng code as follow and it should work

```
    String tempString = sb.toString().substring(1); // Remove first colon
    System.out.println("\nInitial string before splitting = " + tempString);

    String[] tok = tempString.split("\n:"); //  Split by new line and colon
    System.out.println("\ntok.length = " + tok.length);
    System.out.println("\nArray after splitting of initial string = " + Arrays.toString(tok));

    for(String string:tok){
        System.out.println("\nStarting to match values for string = " + string);
        if(string.contains(":")){
            int last=string.lastIndexOf(':');
            String tag=string.substring(0,last);
            String[] data=string.substring(last+1).split("\n");

            System.out.println("tag = " + tag + ", data = " + Arrays.toString(data));
        }else{
            System.out.println("String \"" + string + "\" does not contain ':' character.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are expecting a multi-line data, split on "\n:" and use regex

```
    String[] tok = sb.toString().split("\n:");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":?(.*):(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
    for(String string:tok){
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String tag = matcher.group(1);
            String data = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println(tag+"_"+data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it guys Thank you all for your valuable Suggestions

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String []args){

 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();  
    sb.append(":20:akshay");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":21:ari");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":22:sachin");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":23:viru");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("hazard");
     sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(":25:sevi");
    String sb1=sb.substring(sb.toString().indexOf(':')+1);

    String[] tok = sb1.toString().split("\n:");
    System.out.println(tok.length);
    for(String string:tok){
       // if(string.contains(":")){
             String[] data=string.split(":");

            String tag=data[0];
            String msgData=data[1];
           System.out.println("tag::"+tag+"::data::"+msgData);

       // }


    }





     }
}
```